# Why auto mapper throw Null Refrence Exception when mapping object to data transfer object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

First of all I have read many similar topics but really I'm confused why I'm getting null refrence exception.

I have an Entity named SendCommentConfiguration :

```
public class SendCommentConfiguration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Configuration { get; set; }
}
```

And DTO of it named SendCommentConfigurationDTO :

```
public class SendCommentConfigurationDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Configuration { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration property is a json object that saved in database.

This is my mapper profile :

```
public class MapperProfiles : Profile
{
    public MapperProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<CommentDTO, Comment>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<ReviewDTO, Review>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<WebsiteDTO, Websites>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CommentGroupDTO, CommentGroup>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<SendCommentConfigurationDTO, SendCommentConfiguration>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

And here I'm mapping SendCommentConfiguration to SendCommentConfigurationDTO :

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SendCommentConfigurationDTO>> GetAllSendRequests()
    {
        var result = await _reportsRepository.GetAllSendRequests();
        var mappedResult = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SendCommentConfigurationDTO>>(result);

        return mappedResult;
    }
```

Result variable is not null and has 55 records of SendCommentConfiguration Model but when I'am mapping to DTO, MappedResult is null and I'm getting NullRefrence Exception.

Comment: What type is the variable 'result'?  What is the signature of GetAllSendRequests?

Comment: @NeilW reuslt type is : IEnumerable<SendCommentConfiguration>, if you mean the return type of GetAllSendRequest is IEnumerable<SendCommentConfiguration>

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: Have you defined _mapper correctly in your constructor?

Comment: @bsod_ Thank you, The problem was for defining _mapper in wrong way in constructor.